Prevent chart to resize due to long labels
i am using chart.js and react-chartjs-2. I have this polar chart and a dropdown at top left, as seen in the screenshots, they get resized due to long labels. when I give an empty array to display no labels, so the chart size stays the same, and the labels are the issue here.  is there any way to make the chart stay always the same size regardless of length of labels ? Or I just want to make white circle div element always be in the middle of the chart. 
I have tried setting maintainAspectRatio: false , using fixed dimensions for chart and parent of chart, I already have min max values, some of other questions on SO (link) but did not solve it.
EDIT: I am also open for solutions to make the white absolute div element in the middle somehow make it always middle of the chart.
this is the actual issue
here is my options object;
{
            elements: {
              arc: {
                offset: -160,
              },
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              r: {
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                beginAtZero: true,
                ticks: {
                  display: false, // 0-10 scale,
                },
                grid: {
                  display: true,

                  color: function (ctx: ScriptableScaleContext, _options: AnyObject) {
                    if (ctx.index === 10) return "rgba(27,22,70,0.4)";
                    if (ctx.index === 6) return "rgba(249,35,7,0.4)";
                    return "rgba(222,222,222,0.5)";
                  },
                },
                angleLines: {
                  display: false,
                },
                pointLabels: {
                  display: true,
                  callback: function (label: string) {
                    return label; // Customize the label if needed
                  },
                  centerPointLabels: true,

                  font: function () {
                    return { size: 13 };
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            plugins: {
              legend: {
                display: false,
              },
              datalabels: {
                anchor: "end",
                align: "start",
                color: "white",
                font: {
                  // weight: "bold",
                  size: 24,
                },

                
              },
            },

and here is my data object;
const perceptionDataGesundheit: ChartData<"polarArea", number[], string[]> = {
  labels: labels_gesundheit,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Perception",
      backgroundColor: color_perception,
      borderColor: color_perception,
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: [7.2, 6.1, 7.7],
      spacing: 160,
    },
  ],
}

and here are the screenshots;



There are multiple ways to approach this, but a serious solution would require a runnable, forkable example. One strategy might be to 1) make actual labels of size zero; 2) set a layout.padding (scriptable) that would accommodate
all existing labels; 3) draw the actual labels yourself on the free space of the canvas. I have a sketch of a solution based on that, but at point 3) I used chartjs-plugin-annotation to draw the labels. Supposing this fiddle illustrates the issue, this one
sketches the solution.

@kikon thank you for your approach and work. I needed to point that this is actually a dynamic chart, some of other dropdown items are 4 elements, some of them 6 and maybe it may increase. So I need some dynamic solution.

I wonder if a fully dynamic solution is possible - you can't really prepare for the labels you don't know. My guess is the best solution to avoid resizing is to pre-allocate a reasonable space for the labels (based on the labels you already have) and do something (clip, shorten, etc) to those that extend beyond that.

@kikon I just did some workarounds, seems like there are no direct solutions. And my workaround seems okay for now. you may see my answer below

Have you tried with the grace property on scales.r ?
That should add a padding around the chart so that labels don't affect its size

it doesn't seem to appear as possible field, maybe grace property is only for linear charts ?

Yes, sorry, that seems to be the case

So my workaround was to truncate labels after 10 characters. And for hover of tooltip, I added a custom tooltip which can be found here
EDIT: the issue still persists, the labels at the left hemisphere is kind of pushing the chart and causing resize, help still needed.
EDIT 2: There is a workaround, I added another chart with full length labels (I still split into subarrays if its more then 1 word string), and then I use 0 opacity background color for bars and I give empty strings for actual colored bars. So that it does not matter if labeled chart is big or small, I dont see its bars. And colored bar chart stays -generally- same due to having no labels.
